# Can't correctly decode jwt payload using base64 -d

Tags: shell, jwt, base64

JWT's consist of three sections, separated by a dot:
header.payload.signature

I have the following payload, which I am trying to decode in the terminal using the `base64 -d` command:

```
  payload=eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTY3OTMxMzgyMSwiaWF0IjoxNjc5MTQxMDIxLCJqdGkiOiIzZjM4ZTVmZTBmNGE0N2E0ODg2MGM4M2FmYmNhNTAzZiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEwfQ
```

When trying to decode the payload using `echo $payload | base64 -d`, I get the following output:

```
{"token_type":"refresh","exp":1679313821,"iat":1679141021,"jti":"3f38e5fe0f4a47a48860c83afbca503%
```

The **output does not contain the whole json**, it is cut off.

When using `atob(payload)` in a chrome javascript console, this is the output:

```
{"token_type":"refresh","exp":1679313821,"iat":1679141021,"jti":"3f38e5fe0f4a47a48860c83afbca503f","user_id":10}
```

**This is the correct json output** that I expected from decoding the payload!

**I have the following questions:**

1. Why do these outputs differ, when as far as I know, both functions just base64 decode their input?
2. What can I do to decode the payload in the terminal using `base64 -d` or a similar command?

Thanks in advance!

**Additional Info**

1. `which base64` returns `/usr/bin/base64`
2. I'm on OS X

Answer (score 0):

Your `$payload` value has a Base64 encoding, but lacks the final padding. From [Wikipedia: Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding):

> Because Base64 is a six-bit encoding, and because the decoded values are divided into 8-bit octets, every four characters of Base64-encoded text (4 sextets = 4 × 6 = 24 bits) represents three octets of unencoded text or data (3 octets = 3 × 8 = 24 bits). This means that when the length of the unencoded input is not a multiple of three, the encoded output must have padding added so that its length is a multiple of four. The padding character is `=`, which indicates that no further bits are needed to fully encode the input. […]
>
> The padding character is not essential for decoding, since the number of missing bytes can be inferred from the length of the encoded text. In some implementations, the padding character is mandatory, while for others it is not used.

As it turns out, the JWT token is reluctant to produce the padding characters, while your `base64` decoder requires their presence. The actual token in question has 150 characters, which is two short of being divisible by four. Thus, simply appending these two missing characters would resolve the issue for this particular token, while inferring the number of appended characters from the length of the variable's value would resolve it for the general case:

```bash
echo "$payload==" | base64 -d
# or
echo "$payload$(printf %$(((4-${#payload}%4)%4))s | tr ' ' =)" | base64 -d
```

```json
{"token_type":"refresh","exp":1679313821,"iat":1679141021,"jti":"3f38e5fe0f4a47a48860c83afbca503f","user_id":10}
```

Alternatively, use a decoder that can handle an unbalanced padding, such as the command-line JSON processor [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) (which you could also use for directly post-processing the decoded token, if needed):

```bash
echo "$payload" | jq -R '@base64d | fromjson'
# or
jq -n --arg p "$payload" '$p | @base64d | fromjson'
```

```json
{
  "token_type": "refresh",
  "exp": 1679313821,
  "iat": 1679141021,
  "jti": "3f38e5fe0f4a47a48860c83afbca503f",
  "user_id": 10
}
```